# Function does not work when started by multiprocess

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a C function allocates an integer, passes the pointer to a callback function before returning the pointer.

```
void change_state(int gpio, int level, uint32_t tick, void *ptr){
    if (level == 1){
        printf("Button was pressed!\n");
        *((int*)ptr) += 1;
    }
}

int * allocate_void_ptr_start_watchdog(int BUTTON){
    void *current_state_ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)); /*Creates a ptr of size int*/
    *((int*)current_state_ptr) = 0; /*Casts ptr to type int and set to 0*/
    gpioSetAlertFuncEx(BUTTON, change_state, current_state_ptr); /*Function to watch for GPIO state change*/
    return current_state_ptr; 
}
```

The return value is then passed back to Python:

```
allocate_ptr_start_watchdog = button_functions.allocate_void_ptr_start_watchdog
allocate_ptr_start_watchdog.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
ptr = allocate_ptr_start_watchdog(BUTTON)
```

Using a `while True` loop as follows works as expected (1 press of button at GPIO 25 will turn lights on, second press turns it off)

```
while True:
    current_val = ptr.contents.value
    if current_val == 0:
        continue
    elif current_val == 1:
        button_functions.turn_on_lights(LED_1, LED_2)
    else:
        button_functions.clear_all(LED_1, LED_2)
        ptr.contents.value = 0
```

However once I try to use multiprocessing the function breaks as the button presses don't turn on or off the lights anymore. However, the `printf` from the C library still prints so I doubt it's an issue with the library.

```
def button_start(ptr):
    while True:
        current_val = ptr.contents.value
        if current_val == 0:
            continue
        elif current_val == 1:
            button_functions.turn_on_lights(LED_1, LED_2)
        else:
            button_functions.clear_all(LED_1, LED_2)
            ptr.contents.value = 0


multiprocessing.Process(target=button_start, args=(ptr,)).start()
```

This is running on Raspbian Buster with kernel 5.10.63-v7l+. What am I missing/failing to see here?

Comment: Mind telling us what OS you're running this on? `multiprocessing` uses a different spawning mechanism (`fork` rather than `spawn`) on Linux systems, and that may affect the way your code is getting loaded.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo 
Currently running code on Linux, more specifically Raspbian buster, kernel is 5.10.63.
Actually this is the issue, I have another part in my code which also calls multiprocessing which works fine but that part is a python while loop.

Comment: what happens if you move *all* the c interaction code to the multiprocessing fn? i.e. define the ptr in the multiprocessing fn, rather than passing it.  also add some debugging to your fn: print when it gets the value, and when it tries to turn the lights on or off, so that you can see what exactly is failing.

Comment: Incidentally it's normally possible to get gpio access from python, or via the virtual files in `/sys/class/gpio`.  That's a workaround and what you're doing ought to be possible too, but it might be worth trying.  (avoiding the c code entirely).

Comment: @2e0byo I have a constraint of having to work with the GPIO with only C. However I realized that what seems to be going on is that since the child process does not share the same state as the parent process, the MP version of the code does not have its ptr updated by the watchdog function.

Comment: @ZivOfir yes, that's what I expected would happen, hence the suggestion to make the pointer in the MP fn.  Anything you pass to a MP fn has to be threadsafe, and a bare pointer obv isn't, but I don't know what MP does about that.  [Do I take it you've absolutely confirmed the MP code isn't getting the event, i.e. it's def the read and not the write which is failing? most likely, but it's good to be sure]

Comment: @2e0byo I have tried placing the ptr allocation into MP but it still doesn't work (printing value returns 0 even after pressing button). I was looking into using mp.Value but I can't find a suitable data type for LP_c_long, using c_int64 or c_long/c_int causes it to tell me that it `expected a int and not LP_c_long`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239157/discussion-between-2e0byo-and-ziv-ofir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the MP process needs to connect back to the pigpio daemon there needs to be a function that performs that.

```
int connect_to_daemon(){ /*Connect to pigpio daemon*/
    printf("Connecting to daemon\n");
    int daemon_instance = pigpio_start("192.168.86.234", NULL);
    printf("Successfully connected to daemon\n");
    return daemon_instance;
}
```

We can then assign a variable to this instance in Python `daemon_instance = button_function.connect_to_daemon()` before calling our callback function.

```
int * start_callback(int daemon_instance, int BUTTON){
    void *current_state_ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)); /*Creates a ptr of size int*/
    *((int*)current_state_ptr) = 0; /*Casts ptr to type int and set to 0*/
    callback_ex(daemon_instance, BUTTON, FALLING_EDGE, change_state, current_state_ptr);
    return current_state_ptr;
}
```

In Python:

```
ptr = button_functions.start_callback(daemon_instance, BUTTON)
print(ptr.contents.value)  # This should return the correct value now
```

Big thanks to 2e0byo!